# Very slow performance when running queries against table with nvarchar(max) column in Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-performance

I am suffering from horrendous performance issues using a Azure Sql DB.

Its one table in particular with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RawTwitter](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[IsError] [bit] NULL,
[ErrorDescription] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[IsProcessed] [bit] NULL,
[IsRunResult] [bit] NULL,
[RawJson] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
```

The RawJson field is the culprit. If I do a SELECT that contains that field my query takes minutes - like 20 minutes! If I take that column out of the query its instant. There are only about 45,000 records in that table!

I'm not getting this issue on local so I scripted that table and found that it differed from that on Azure. On local, the following is appended to the table script:

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_RawTwitter] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

but on Azure version the TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY] is omitted. Having done some more digging it would appear that Azure does not allow that last keyword? And it would appear that this affects how large text fields are stored.

This would seem to be the obvious reason there is such a big difference in performance between my local and staging.  What other things can I try to get around this performance nightmare?

Comment: run below query ,see what is wait type `select 
session_id,
start_time,
command,
db_name(ec.database_id) as dbname,
blocking_session_id,
wait_type,
last_wait_type,
wait_time,
cpu_time,
logical_reads,
reads,
writes,
((database_transaction_log_bytes_used +database_transaction_log_bytes_reserved)/1024)/1024 as logusageMB,
txt.text,
pln.query_plan
 from sys.dm_exec_requests ec
 cross apply
 sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec.sql_handle) txt
 cross apply
 sys.dm_exec_query_plan(ec.plan_handle) pln
 join
 sys.dm_tran_database_transactions trn
 on trn.transaction_id=ec.transaction_id`

Comment: also paste execution  plan,your performance tier

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar problem with a column that contains JSON even though there is never that much data in this column on the records I am returning, when this column is included in the "select" it add over 25% onto the amount of time the query takes and I am not sure why.